# Can't resolve .setText

Tags: android

**[SOLVED] Silly typo:** This code solved my problem:

`dateTimeEasyText.setText ("");` changed to `dateAndTimeEasyText.setText ("");`

.

**PROBLEM:**
I have an ImageView which on click should reset two of my TextViews, one containing HighScore (numbers) and the other TextView containing Date & Time (String).

My coding:

```
 public void resetHighcoreButtonEasy(View v) {
        highscoreEasyText.setText("");
        dateTimeEasyText.setText ("");

    }//resetHighcoreButtonEasy ends here
```

.

Printscreen on the coding and the message:
[image]

.

**JAVA-file:**

```
public class HighScoreActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

TextView highscoreEasyText;
TextView dateAndTimeEasyText;
ImageView resetHighcoreButtonEasy;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_high_score);


    resetHighcoreButtonEasy = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.resetHighcoreButtonEasy);


    SharedPreferences sharedPrefsEasyHighScore = getSharedPreferences("Prefs_EasyHighScore",MODE_PRIVATE);
    int storedEasyHighScore = sharedPrefsEasyHighScore.getInt("easy_highScore",0);
    highscoreEasyText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.highscoreEasyText);
    highscoreEasyText.setText("" + storedEasyHighScore + " p");
    highscoreEasyText.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.highscore_text));

    SharedPreferences sharedPrefsEasyDateTime = getSharedPreferences("Prefs_EasyDateTime",MODE_PRIVATE);
    String dateTime = sharedPrefsEasyDateTime.getString("easy_date_time", null);
    dateAndTimeEasyText = (TextView)findViewById(dateTimeEasyText);
    dateAndTimeEasyText.setText(dateTime);
    dateAndTimeEasyText.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.highscore_text));

}//onCreate ends here


 public void resetHighcoreButtonEasy(View v) {
        highscoreEasyText.setText("");
        dateTimeEasyText.setText ("");

    }//resetHighcoreButtonEasy ends here
```

Comment: write dateAndTimeEasyText.setText (""); instead of dateTimeEasyText.setText ("");

Comment: you are using wrong variable name

Comment: That said, this question should be closed because it doesn't give any contribution to SO

Comment: for finding id of dateAndTimeEasyText you are using dateTimeEasyText. That is also wrong

Comment: Thank you so much....! It's because of this method who started it: `dateAndTimeEasyText = (TextView)findViewById(dateTimeEasyText)` - it didn't allow me to name it `"dateTimeEasyText"` and I therefore changed it to `"dateAndTimeEasyText"` and forgot about....Geeez! -.-'

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong variable to access dateTimeEasyText.

As per your declaration it is suppose to be dateAndTimeEasyText.

Spell mistake.

Comment: Thank you so much....! It's because of this method who started it: `dateAndTimeEasyText = (TextView)findViewById(dateTimeEasyText)` - it didn't allow me to name it `"dateTimeEasyText"` and I therefore changed it to `"dateAndTimeEasyText"` and forgot it....Geeez! -.-'

Answer (score 1):

Just a typo. You have:

```
TextView dateAndTimeEasyText;
```

And in your method you use it without `And`:

```
dateTimeEasyText.setText ("");
```

You should use:

```
dateAndTimeEasyText.setText("");
```

So `dateTimeEasyText` isn't a TextView, and it hasn't got a method `setText(java.lang.String)`.

Comment: Thank you so much....! It's because of this method who started it: `dateAndTimeEasyText = (TextView)findViewById(dateTimeEasyText)` - it didn't allow me to name it `"dateTimeEasyText"` and I therefore changed it to `"dateAndTimeEasyText"` and forgot about it....Geeez! -.-'

Answer (score 1):

```
 dateTimeEasyText  should be  `dateAndTimeEasyText`.

 dateAndTimeEasyText.setText("");
```

Comment: Thank you so much....! It's because of this method who started it: `dateAndTimeEasyText = (TextView)findViewById(dateTimeEasyText)` - it didn't allow me to name it `"dateTimeEasyText"` and I therefore changed it to `"dateAndTimeEasyText"` and forgot about it....Geeez! -.-'

Answer (score 0):

In layout xml for ImageView resetHighcoreButtonEasy onClick should be there:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/resetHighcoreButtonEasy"
        ...
        ...
        android:onClick="resetHighcoreButtonEasy"
        ..... />
```

This line of code should be there to give click event from xml

**android:onClick="resetHighcoreButtonEasy"**

And your function should be public and have a param View in it, as you have done already

**public void resetHighcoreButtonEasy(View v) {**